# Airflow Parallel Task with Pandas

Tags: python, airflow

hope you are doing fine
I am struggling on small issue with airflow here is what I want to do

- I am reading a file and then based on the file I want to apply a transformation on columns and wait for all task to complete and create a new file
  Here is how my pipeline looks like
  [image]

as you can see nothing fancy just applying some transformation on columns

```
def process_file_1(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["type"]  = df['type'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df


def process_file_2(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["director"]  = df['director'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df

def process_file_3(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["title"]  = df['title'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df
```

- Issue is everything is working great seems like when the process ends in process.csv changes are being taken place only on one column

[image]

here is the entire DAG Code :

```
try:
    import os
    import sys

    from datetime import timedelta,datetime
    from airflow import DAG

    # Operators
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
    from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

    import pandas as pd

    print("All Dag modules are ok ......")

except Exception as e:
    print("Error  {} ".format(e))


# ===============================================
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
    'email': ['shahsoumil519@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}
dag  = DAG(dag_id="project", schedule_interval="@once", default_args=default_args, catchup=False)
# ================================================


def read_file(**context):
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dags/common/netflix_titles.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)


def process_file_1(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["type"]  = df['type'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df


def process_file_2(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["director"]  = df['director'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df

def process_file_3(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    df["title"]  = df['title'].apply(lambda x:  'ok')
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)
    return df

def complete_task(**context):
    df = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="df")
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dags/common/process.csv")
    df.to_csv(path)



with DAG(dag_id="project", schedule_interval="@once", default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    read_file = PythonOperator(task_id="read_file",python_callable=read_file,provide_context=True,)

    process_file_1 = PythonOperator(task_id="process_file_1",python_callable=process_file_1,provide_context=True,)
    process_file_2 = PythonOperator(task_id="process_file_2",python_callable=process_file_2,provide_context=True,)
    process_file_3 = PythonOperator(task_id="process_file_3",python_callable=process_file_3,provide_context=True,)

    complete_task = PythonOperator(task_id="complete_task",python_callable=complete_task,provide_context=True,)


read_file >> process_file_1
read_file >> process_file_2
read_file >> process_file_3

process_file_1 >> complete_task
process_file_2 >> complete_task
process_file_3 >> complete_task
```

Comment: You can't do this in parallel. each xcom_push creates a new copy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot parallelize the operation with same object reference. Instead you parallelize the data.

- Split file into 3
- Push all of them with 3 unique keys into xcom
- Pull them in 3 parallel tasks and perform transformations on all the columns and push output with same keys
- In the final step, pull back all the files and concat to get final output